# Database Query Optimization Issue NcharLiterals

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc, tomcat8

We wanted to persist japanese characters in oracle database running through tomcat server. So we added below properties to java opts and changed the data type of field in a table to NVARCHAR.

```
-Doracle.jdbc.defaultNChar=true
-Doracle.jdbc.convertNcharLiterals=true
```

After adding this, all the queries executing in database are running very slow and performance is very bad.

Please let me know the best way to utilize these properties to capture multi language characters.

Comment: what is your nls characterset?

Comment: NLS_CHARACTERSET=WE8ISO8859P15

Comment: DBA recommends to AL32UTF8 conversion. Do I have any other workaround to address this issue?